# How to use bash clear from within a ruby cli

Tags: ruby, bash, terminal, command-line-interface

Clear works fine when I am just browsing my files in my terminal. However within my CLI program,

I have tried clear and can't get it to clear the user's screen.

```
`clear`
```

Why doesn't this currently work inside my CLI code?

Sleep works.

```
`sleep 5`


  def dealer_hits_until_17
    @new_hand = false
    while hand_score(@dealer_hand) < 17 && @new_hand == false
      puts "Dealer Hits! His hand is now #{@dealer_hand}xxx"
      hit(@dealer_hand)
      `sleep 1`
      `clear`
    end
    if @new_hand == false
      compare_hand_value
    end
  end
```

Does anyone know what I can put into my Ruby CLI so that the screen clears?

Comment: just carefully study the documentation and if you do not find what you ask questions [Ruby#Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clear` outputs ANSI sequences to clear the screen. [`cmd`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60) capture output of the `cmd` command and return it.; This prevent screen clear.

Instead of `..`, use `Kernel#system` to clear the screen:

```
system('clear')
```

Comment: @bliof, Using `puts`, you get an additional newline printed. IMHO, `print \`clear\`` should be used instead. Thank you for comment.